# jQuery validation error message shows when it shouldn't

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple form with two radio buttons and a submit button.

If none of the radios are checked, when submit is clicked, this causes an error. As it should. Then clicking a radio button makes the error go away.

**The problem:** After the error has disappeared, if I click the other radio button, the error shows again briefly. Similarly when I click the submit button it shows briefly. Why is this?

[Here's a fiddle showing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/4bz6xye5/2/)

Here's the code:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="options" class="radioB">
  <input type="radio" name="options" class="radioB">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
</form>
<div id="error--holder"></div>

$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        options: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        options: "Whoops! Please indicate who.",
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $('#error--holder').html(error.text()+' <a href=#>Go fix it...</a>').fadeIn();
    },
    success: function(error) {
        $('#error--holder').fadeOut();
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        return false; // stop
    }
});
```

Comment: In errorPlacement method you can check error message length if its length should be more than one then show error else else nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply trick, If error text available in element then `fadeIn()` error message, see below sample code

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if(error.text())
        $('#error--holder').html(error.text()+' <a href=#>Go fix it...</a>').fadeIn();
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4bz6xye5/3/)